# Can I train a model using the notebook instance of AWS sagemaker?

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I want to train a PyTorch based model using AWS SageMaker but I don't know how to use the ML Training services. So I was wondering if it is possible to simply train the model using the notebook instance and uploading the model to the S3 bucket? Also, how would I ensure That I do not end up paying more than I need to?